# < (меньше) или != (не равно) в цикле for?

Tags: c++, циклы, любой-язык

Какой тип цикла в обобщённом коде выбрать?

```
for (auto i = first; i < last; ++i) {   
    // ...
}

for (auto i = first; i != last; ++i) {   
    // ...
}
```

[CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t143-dont-write-unintentionally-non-generic-code) говорит, что второй, но практически всегда встречаю первый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CppCoreGuidelines говорит, что второй вариант более generic (а если написано generic, читаем "шаблоны" :) ). Очень легко увидеть, что если есть какой-то связанный список, то операцию равно-не равно легко определить, а вот больше-меньше - сложно. Это и есть причиной такой рекомендации.

Там же написано

> Of course, range-for is better

и я бы добавил, что если есть возможность использовать готовый алгоритм, то лучше его и использовать вместо цикла.

Но для простого пользовательского кода (особенно, если там int) я бы не использовал != - нужно обязательно сделать дополнительную проверку на first <= last.

В своей практике я видел код, который использует != и он иногда приводил к багам... И вот самый красивый (в оригинале он был немного красивее)

```
unsigned int last = get_last();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != last; i+=2) {
  //..
}
```

Comment: а разве под шаблонами тут не template? А generic - это что-то вроде "общий подход"?

Comment: _i+=2_ - отработает норм для четного last :-D может так и задумано

Comment: шаблоны - это и есть generic. В втором случае никто не гарантировал, что там будет четное (на самом деле там были итераторы и в цикле вызывался лишний раз инкремент, но это отдельная история, я упростил пример)

Answer (score 2):

Если работаете с индексами - то все равно, первый в определенном смысле предпочтительнее (вдруг в цикле нужно будет `i` увеличить дополнительно и появится шанс "проскочить" `last` :)).

Но если с итераторами — то очевидно, что второй.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: почему с итераторами очевидно второй? :) там разве нельзя "проскочить"? :)

Comment: имхо то, что второй вариант крашнется/сделает что-то не то при наличии бага с проскоком лучше, чем у нас есть баг с проскоком, но мы его не заметили из-за <

Comment: @Руслан, проблема с проскоком в том, что ее тоже можно не заметить

Comment: а я не смог распарсить комментарий от Руслана...

Comment: @KoVadim, суть в том, что если неправильно меняем `i` внутри цикла, то если случайно сделаем его больше - просто выйдем из цикла и вроде как нормальное завершение, в то время как с `!=` - будем висеть пока не попадем в сам `i`